# deployment minifiter driver using occur errors

Tags: visual-studio-2012, driver, minifilter

I'm writing my first minifilter driver. 
My Environment is :
Host OS: Win7 (64bit)
Guest OS: Win Server 2008 R2
VMWare:8.0.2
VS 2012 and WDK8.0

First, I write a Kmdf demo according http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx. It runs correctly.
Then I create a minifilter driver using VS2012, and build it. But I failed to deployment.
Do minifilter drivers and KMDF drivers have different setting  in **Package Properties->Driver Install** or I failed to install my vs2012 and wdk8 correctly?

The Error Dialog reads:
Driver Testing
An error occurred deploying the drivers in the solution:Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: kmdf is different than minifilter, you may want to look at minifilter specific instructions.

Comment: In KMDF Driver's inf generated by VS2012, this piece of code      `[Standard.NT$ARCH$]
%KmdfSmall.DeviceDesc%=KmdfSmall_Device, Root\KmdfSmall `              
appears, and i can do settings accroding to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx), **KMDF Package 
Properties->Configuration Properties>Driver Install>Deployment** and **Enable deployment** then**enter the hardware ID**for my KMDF driver. But Minifilter driver's inf doesn't have [Standard.NT$ARCH$], and how should i set minifilter's  Hardware ID to deployit on target computer??